# Insert into table1 the difference between staging table 1 and table 1

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to insert into table 1 this result:

```
select * from table1
minus
select * from stag_table1
```

The following query does not work.

Do Have I to use a cursor?

Might somebody help me?

Comment: There is no "following query." Also: what do you mean by "insert" - do you need to duplicate the rows from table1 that are not in stag_table1? That doesn't make much sense. Do you actually have to insert into table 1 the rows that are in stag_table1 and not (already) in table1? That makes more sense. You do not need a cursor (or PL/SQL at all), but you do need to show some sample data (so, at least, we can see the columns).

Comment: YES, by using stored procedure (plsql) I have to insert into table 1 the rows that are in stag_table1. The columns are the same for both table:

Comment: Why "by using stored procedure"? What is wrong with a standard SQL query? I am sure there must be a reason, but you didn't say what it is.

Comment: this is my code: PROCEDURE SG_AN_FDP_INS (P_CUR_RESULT OUT sys_refcursor) AS

BEGIN

OPEN P_CUR_RESULT
FOR

SELECT CODE, DESCRIPTION, SYSCREATEDATE, SYSCREATEUSER, SYSUPDATEDATE, SYSUPDATEUSER, FLAG_DELETED FROM STAG_SG_AN_FDP
MINUS
SELECT CODE, DESCRIPTION, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 967, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 967, 0 FROM SG_AN_FDP;

Comment: Why do you need a procedure for this? This is a trivial INSERT operation, you don't need PL/SQL.

Comment: mathguy has a good possible solution. One reason your code was failing is that by using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the minus select, you will NEVER be removing any records as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will NEVER match the values in your stage table.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial part is:

```
insert into table1 (select * from stag_table1 minus select * from table1);
```

See if this helps.

Comment: OK, than you. But, if I don't want ad ID colum into the stag table, how can I make the difference and insert the value into table 1? In this last I create the ID column with a sequence.

Comment: What happened to "The columns are the same for both tables"? (An EXACT quote from your answer to my Comment.)